# WH_MOUSE_LL hook, avoid getting useless WM_MOUSEMOVE events

Tags: windows, winapi, windows-messages, setwindowshookex

Is there a way, even a dirty hack, to avoid receiving `WM_MOUSEMOVE` events in a `WH_MOUSE_LL` hook? I'm interested only in wheel rotations and buttons. The performance cost of receiving `WM_MOUSEMOVE` is unnacceptable in my scenario.

I cannot use `WH_MOUSE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to tell a hook to not receive particular messages.  When you hook the mouse, especially a low level hook, you receive everything the mouse does.

Comment: in your experience, is it enough to have a thread entirely dedicated to this hook (a simple `GetMessage` loop, a sort of fast dispatching to the main thread, real time priority) to mitigate the performance problems?

Comment: the mouse is not very responsive. This could be caused by the fact that the thread that installed the hook is not entirely dedicated to the message loop (it pumps them with `PeekMessage` then `GetMessage`, it does not wait for them in a blocking call to `GetMessage`).